# what is the difference between HostFactory.Run and HostFactory.New

Tags: .net, topshelf

I've a need to use topshelf in the project I'm in and have a simple question I hope. Everything works just fine when I'm using `HostFactory.Run`, but I thought that it seemed more reasonable to use `HostFactory.New` by just reading the name on the function and that is used here: http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/configuration/config_api.html.

However in the more simple example, http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/configuration/quickstart.html, the `HostFactory.Run` is used insted of `HostFactory.New`. So what is the difference?

Comment: See the source - https://github.com/phatboyg/Topshelf/blob/master/src/Topshelf/HostFactory.cs

Comment: @stuartd, thank you. So basically the new creates a host but run creates and runs it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Run` pretty much just contains:

```
return New(configureCallback).Run();
```

So `Run` is just convenience method to create and immediately run the instance instead of just creating the instance as `New` does.

Comment: There is more to it.  See LoveJenny's answer.

Answer (score 17):

`HostFactory.Run` will eat all exception, so it will silent exit, and you never know what caused it.

> HostFactory.New

will throw the exception.

Comment: Kind of necro, but this needs an update.

Just ran into this problem where "run" would execute without throwing anything but the process never actually ran.

True to SO, the useful answers get downvoted.